# how to limit the value length in object array by class validator typescript?

Tags: typescript, class-validator

I want to make rule by class validator, value of name's length should be min length = 1, max length = 100.

but i'm stuck during 3 days..

each value of name should be between 1-100 characters.

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}, {'id': 2, 'name': '0123456789001234567890012345678900123456789001234567890012345678900123456789001234567890012345678901'}]
```

// it's okay becuase 100 characters.

i tried, and googled so many times.. but nothing has worked fine. what should i do??

```
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger'
import { Length } from 'class-validator'
import { Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm'
import { MaxLenPostFolderName } from './createPostFolder.dto'

class RenamePostFolder {
  @ApiProperty()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @ApiProperty({ description: 'post folder name' })
  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: MaxLenPostFolderName, nullable: false })
  // @Length(1, MaxLenPostFolderName, { each: true })
  name: string
}

// 
export class RenamePostFolderDto {
  @ApiProperty({ required: true })
  @Length(1, MaxLenPostFolderName)
  name: string
}

// created new rename dto, because spec updated, to make 'batch rename'
export class RenamePostFolderDtoV2 {
  @ApiProperty({ required: true, type: [RenamePostFolder] })
  // @Length(1, MaxLenPostFolderName)
  postFolders: RenamePostFolder[]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`MinLength`](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validation-decorators) and [`MaxLength`](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validation-decorators)

```
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { MaxLength, MinLength } from 'class-validator';

const MIN_LENGTH = 1;
const MAX_LENGTH = 100;

export class RenamePostFolderDto {
  @ApiProperty({ required: true })
  @MinLength(MIN_LENGTH)
  @MaxLength(MAX_LENGTH)
  name: string;
}
```

It's listed in multiple examples from [class-validator's documentation](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#usage) on GitHub